# Is it possible to have a hibernate generated ID provided to a non-linked entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities, for the sake of convenience: parent, child
My child entity has a many to one relationship with the parent.

For each entity I also have a 'log' entity which has mostly the same fields as the corresponding entity, with the addition of a record start and end timestamp. The idea being I can track the movement of data in the parent and child entities over time.

My issue is that, while I have an integer field referencing the 'parent ID' on the child log entity, I can't populate this on the initial run of my service, or when a new parent & children are created because no IDs exist at that point.

So my question is, is it possible to make a reference to a parent ID in my child log table **WITHOUT** adding a OneToMany relationship to the parent in my log entity in order to reference the parent ID without creating a complex join of parent -> child -> childLog in order to filter by parentID and childID?

Answer (score 0):

You can query with JOIN...ON:

```
SELECT p
FROM PurchaseOrder p
JOIN PurchaseOrderItem i ON p.id = i.purchaseOrderId
GROUP BY p.id
```

See also: https://martinelli.ch/how-to-join-two-entities-without-mapped-relationship/

Comment: I was trying to avoid trying to create a join, as it'd be across 3 tables: parent -> child -> childLog.
My question was more related to the hibernate side than the SQL: can I create a reference in hibernate to an ID of an entity that doesn't exist yet without creating a relationship (e.g. oneToMany etc).

Comment: No you can't. You must have a reference